# Vectorizing drift change in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

Here's the Python code

```
t0 = df['Temperature'].iloc[0] # Dataframe df with column 'Temperature' is already given
df['DriftedTemp'] = None

for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if(np.abs(df['Temperature'].iloc[i] - t0) > toffset): # toffset is a parameter that is given
        df['DriftedTemp'].iloc[i] = df['Temperature'].iloc[i]
        t0 = df['Temperature'].iloc[i]
```

It figures out the rows when the temperature drifted from the previously recorded value by more than "toffset", and updates the "DriftedTemp" column at that row with this new value, and "t0" as well to the "Temperature" at a point where the drift happens.

The issue with such codes is that the current value depends on the previous value when it was evaluated in a previous row. Vectorization treats each column as vectors so the changed state of previous rows do not get reflected through simple vectorization.

This can be implemented using a while loop and vectorization but I cannot think of a simple vectorization technique without any loops to accomplish the same task.

Comment: You need to include an example frame that we can work with

Comment: I am new to SO so I did not know that. I will keep that in mind for next time. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vectorization might not be possible since the computation of drift depends on the previous state of drift having said that this is a good use case for using `numba` basically create a function with the logic and then compile it with numba to achieve C like speeds.

```
import numba

@numba.njit
def drift(temperatures, toffset):
    drift = np.full_like(temperatures, fill_value=np.nan, dtype='float')

    for i, t in enumerate(temperatures):
        if i == 0:
            t0 = t        
        elif abs(t - t0) > toffset:
            t0 = drift[i] = t

    return drift


df['DriftedTemp'] = drift(df['Temperature'].to_numpy(), 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read about numba on their 5-minute guide website. As long as the function uses basic Python and maybe numpy, the compiler compiled in the nopython mode should really speed things up. Is there some source where they mention more about when numba fails to compile? I know that it does not recognize pandas. Is that it? If you can point me to some source regarding that, I'd appreciate it.